# 500 Internal Error in ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

So I have this script

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >

window.onload = function(){

        var request = $.ajax({
        url: "../wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/admin/test.php",
        type: "GET",            
        dataType: "html"
        });

        request.done(function(msg) {
            $(".recent-orders").html(msg);          
        });

        request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
        });

}
```

and my test.php file.

```
    $args = array(
    'numberposts'     => 8,
    'orderby'         => 'post_date',
    'order'           => 'DESC',
    'post_type'       => 'shop_order',
    'post_status'     => 'publish'
);
$orders = get_posts( $args );
if ($orders) :
    foreach ($orders as $order) :

        $this_order = new WC_Order( $order->ID );

        echo '
        <li>
            <span class="order-status '.sanitize_title($this_order->status).'">'.ucwords(__($this_order->status, 'woocommerce')).'</span> <a href="'.admin_url('post.php?post='.$order->ID).'&action=edit">' . get_the_time( __( 'l jS \of F Y h:i:s A', 'woocommerce' ), $order->ID ) . '</a><br />
            <small>'.sizeof($this_order->get_items()).' '._n('item', 'items', sizeof($this_order->get_items()), 'woocommerce').' <span class="order-cost">'.__('Total:', 'woocommerce' ) . ' ' . woocommerce_price($this_order->order_total).'</span></small>
        </li>';

    endforeach;
endif;
```

Yes, that is from woocommerce. I'm trying to get another set of products and add it into ul list. But I get this 500 internal server error every time I request.

I'm using LAMP server to test and I've already tested it in a hosted server. The error persists.

Any help or idea will be appreciated. The javascript works because I've tested it with just an echo of a string and it place it on the recent-order ul.

Comment: If the JS works and you're getting a 500, you should tag the question as PHP

Comment: Check server error log if possible. 500 internal server error could mean any error in server-side scripts (p.s. the question focus shouldn't be on JS)

Comment: I added a php tag. I kinda missed that.

Comment: if that is the real contents of your php file where are your PHP tags? e.g. `<?php`

Comment: I checked my logs, and I get this line - PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function get_posts() in /home/techstars05/www/test/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/admin/test.php on line 19, referer: http://localhost/restaurantest/wp-admin/

So, I think this is more of a wordpress question than any other.

Comment: Well you are calling a function that doesn't exist in test.php and you have no include statements to include a file that might contain the function, so PHP doesn't know what the function is.

Comment: You should use a tool like Firebug so you can get more info about what's causing the error.

Comment: Fixed it!

So the problem is the PHP is not recognizing the get_post method which is found in

"wp-blog-header.php"

So I just placed `<?php require_once("../../../../wp-blog-header.php"); ?>` on top of my test.php all is good.

Rookie Mistake. Thanks to everyone for giving me the idea to check the logs. I never would have found out that get_posts is not recognized. Thanks!